# How to sort an array of arrays by a key in PHP?

Tags: php

```
Array(
    ["car"] => Array(
                     [12/11/1989] => (...)
                     [6/14/2011] => (...)
                     [5/2/2012] => (...)
               )
    ["sled"] => Array(
                     [1/15/2001] => (...)
                     [4/14/2004] => (...)
                     [5/23/2005] => (...)
               )
    ["boat"] => Array(
                     [12/1/1999] => (...)
                     [6/14/2000] => (...)
                     [8/23/2000] => (...)
               )
)
```

Given the above array structure, I am trying to sort the keys `["boat"], ["sled"], ["car"]` by the first date key in their respective sub-arrays. So the correct key order would now be car, boat, sled. Is there an elegant or easy way to do this with PHP?

Comment: Use `usort()` and provide a function that gets the first key from `array_keys()` of each element, converts them to a date, and compares them.

Comment: Also, if you can setup the arrays so they use timestamps instead of dates it would be a lot easier to sort.

Comment: @Barmar the usort() function will assign new keys to the original outer array which I do not want to happen. I'm aware of uksort() but that will send the keys of the outer array to be sorted which is again not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, `uasort()`. That sorts the values and keeps the key associations.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! i wasn't aware of the uasort() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `uasort()` to sort the array with a user-supplied comparison function, keeping the keys of the associative array.

```
function compare_first_key_date($a, $b) {
    $a_keys = array_keys($a);
    $a_date = strtotime($a_keys[0]);
    $b_keys = array_keys($b);
    $b_date = strtotime($b_keys[0]);
    return $a_date - $b_date;
}
uasort($array, 'compare_first_key_date');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `uasort` and compare the first key value of each array. Cast to a timestring using `strtotime` to simplify date comparisons:

```
<?php

$array = array(
  "car" => array(
     "12/11/1989" => "first element",
     "6/14/2011" => "second element",
     "5/2/2012" => "third element",
  ),
  "sled" => array(
    "1/15/2001" => "first element",
    "4/14/2004" => "second element",
    "5/23/2005" => "third element",
  ),
  "boat" => array(
    "12/1/1999" => "first element",
    "6/14/2000" => "second element",
    "8/23/2000" => "third element",
  ),
);

uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $ts1 = strtotime(reset(array_keys($a)));
    $ts2 = strtotime(reset(array_keys($b)));
    if ($ts1 === $ts2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($ts1 < $ts2) ? -1 : 1;
});

var_export($array);
```

Which will output:

```
array (
  'car' => 
  array (
    '12/11/1989' => 'first element',
    '6/14/2011' => 'second element',
    '5/2/2012' => 'third element',
  ),
  'boat' => 
  array (
    '12/1/1999' => 'first element',
    '6/14/2000' => 'second element',
    '8/23/2000' => 'third element',
  ),
  'sled' => 
  array (
    '1/15/2001' => 'first element',
    '4/14/2004' => 'second element',
    '5/23/2005' => 'third element',
  ),
)
```